# How to wake up RPi CM4 using external signal

Tags: raspberry-pi

How can I wake up the RPi from sleep mode (after the system is turned off) by giving an external signal?

Manually shorted RUN PG and GLOBAL_EN when RPi is asleep resolve this problem but how can I do this use external signal e.g from Arduino?

Answer (score 2):

You just need to pull `GLOBAL_EN` low. Connect `GLOBAL_EN` to a GPIO pin on your microcontroller, and when you want to wake the CM4 up, just pulse it low for >1 ms (value from the CM4 IO Board [datasheet](https://datasheets.raspberrypi.com/cm4io/cm4io-datasheet.pdf), Figure 8). Make sure you don't exceed the maximum voltage on the CM4 GPIO pins; it's selectable between 3.3 V and 1.8 V. The classic Arduino is 5 V IO, so be careful!

To get around this issue, rather than returning `GLOBAL_EN` to high after the wake up pulse, you could set the microcontroller pin to an input (ie, high-Z) and `GLOBAL_EN` will be pulled up internally. You still need to be careful here, and check what the default state of the microcontroller's GPIO pins is when it's reset - you don't want it to be an output and driven high (this is unlikely, but do check!). Of course, you also need to be careful not to drive it high as an output inadvertantly in your code as well.

From the comments, pulling `GLOBAL_EN` low when it's awake will turn it off again. So, run `RUN_PG` to your microcontroller, and only allow `GLOBAL_EN` to be pulled low when `RUN_PG` is also low. This is essentially what is done in the CM4 IO board.

Comment: "If the CM4 is already awake, this will have no effect." this is not true! I tested this solution when CM4 is asleep and pulled down GLOBAL_EN to Low the CM wake up but when CM is running and pull down, the CM immediately turn off! In Datashet for CM4 on p.20 you can read "GLOBAL_EN Input. Drive low to power off CM4. Internally pulled up with a 100K to +5V".

Comment: Ok, edited to reflect that :)